# Pandas updating values in a column using a lookup dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have column in a Pandas dataframe that I want to use to lookup a value of cost in a lookup dictionary.

The idea is that I will update an existing column if the item is there and if not the column will be left blank.

All the methods and solutions I have seen so far seem to create a new column, such as apply and assign methods, but it is important that I preserve the existing data.

Here is my code:

```
lookupDict = {'Apple': 1, 'Orange': 2,'Kiwi': 3,'Lemon': 8}

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Fruits':['Apple','Banana','Kiwi','Cheese'],
                'Pieces':[6, 3, 5, 7],
                'Cost':[88, 55, 65, 55]},)
```

What I want to achieve is lookup the items in the fruit column and if the item is there I want to update the cost column with the dictionary value multiplied by the number of pieces.

For example for Apple the cost is 1 from the lookup dictionary, and in the dataframe the number of pieces is 6, therefore the cost column will be updated from 88 to (6*1) = 6. The next item is banana which is not in the lookup dictionary, therefore the cost in the original dataframe will be left unchanged. The same logic will be applied to the rest of the items.

The only way I can think of achieving this is to separate the lists from the dataframe, iterate through them and then add them back into the dataframe when I'm finished. I am wondering if it would be possible to act on the values in the dataframe without using separate lists??

From other responses I image I have to use the loc indicators such as the following: (But this is not working and I don't want to create a new column)

```
df1.loc[df1.Fruits in lookupDict,'Cost'] = lookupDict[df1.Fruits] * lookupD[df1.Pieces]
```

I have also tried to map but it overwrites all the content of the existing column:

```
 df1['Cost'] = df1['Fruits'].map(lookupDict)*df1['Pieces']
```

EDIT*******

I have been able to achieve it with the following using iteration, however I am still curious if there is a cleaner way to achieve this:

```
#Iteration method

for i,x in zip(df1['Fruits'],xrange(len(df1.index))):
        fruit = (df1.loc[x,'Fruits']) 
        if fruit in lookupDict:
            newCost =   lookupDict[fruit] * df1.loc[x,'Pieces'] 
            print(newCost)
            df1.loc[x,'Cost'] = newCost
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly:

```
mask = df1['Fruits'].isin(lookupDict.keys())
df1.loc[mask, 'Cost'] = df1.loc[mask, 'Fruits'].map(lookupDict) * df1.loc[mask, 'Pieces']

Result:

In [29]: df1
Out[29]:
   Cost  Fruits  Pieces
0     6   Apple       6
1    55  Banana       3
2    15    Kiwi       5
3    55  Cheese       7
```